# How to get caret position in div contentEditable in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to insert emoji icon to a div contentEditable but I can't get the caret position when picking emoji to insert this emoji to the div. In the `<input />` or `<textarea />` element I can get the position of caret by access to `HTMLInputElement.selectionStart`, `selectionEnd` but I don't know how to handle it in div element. Is there any way I can get the caret position from div contentEditable ?

Here is my code:

```
 const inputRef = useRef(null);
 const [text, setText] = useState('');

 const handleInput = (event) => setText(event.target.textContent);

 const handleInsertEmoji = ({ native: emoji }) => {
    inputRef.current.focus();

    const currentCaretPosition = inputRef.current.target?.selectionStart;
    // currentCaretPosition is undefined

    const strBeforeCaret = text.slice(0, currentCaretPosition);
    const strAfterCaret = text.slice(currentCaretPosition, content.length);
    setText(`${strBeforeCaret}${emoji}${strAfterCaret}`);
 }

 return (
   <div>

     <div
       ref={inputRef}
       contentEditable={true}
       onInput={handleInput}
     />

     <EmojiPicker onEmojiSelect={handleInsertEmoji} />

   </div>
 )
```